# Mysql update query not running ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

My mysql query in ASP.NET is not running. I have printed out string session so i know i have the value for it and connection string is working in all other methods so i know the issue is not there. Running the command manually in PHPMyadmin works fine. Another method which looks the same, only with select cmd works.

```
public IActionResult DeleteProfile()
    {
        string session = HttpContext.Session.GetString("session"); /* gets value (customerid) for user session */

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {

            conn.Open();
            string cmdtxt = "UPDATE customer SET active = '0' WHERE customerid = @session";


            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdtxt, conn);

            /**************** SQL PARAMETER ********///

            MySqlParameter parameter = new MySqlParameter();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@session", session);

            /**************** SQL PARAMETER ********///


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.error = "Connection Error!\n" + ex.Message;


        }
        finally
        {

            conn.Close();
            ViewBag.error = "Account deleted";
            HttpContext.Session.Remove("session");
        }                

        return View("../Account/Index");
    }
```

Comment: where your  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); statement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correctly instantiating the `MySqlCommand` and assigning the appropriate parameter, but then you're not doing anything with that command.

You need to execute the query, so it gets sent to the database server:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Ops. I used MySqlDataAdapter on my insert commands in other parts of the code, is it more practial or other pros to use ExecuteNonQuery?